# C++ equivalent of java's instanceof

Tags: java, c++, oop, instanceof

What is the preferred method to achieve the C++ equivalent of java's `instanceof`?

Comment: Preferred by performance and compatibility...

Comment: isn't it fair to ask "instanceof - in what language?"

Comment: @mysticcoder: I get "например на" for Bulgarian, GT doesn't support C++ though

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Try using:

```
if(NewType* v = dynamic_cast<NewType*>(old)) {
   // old was safely casted to NewType
   v->doSomething();
}
```

This requires your compiler to have rtti support enabled.

EDIT:
I've had some good comments on this answer!

Every time you need to use a dynamic_cast (or instanceof) you'd better ask yourself whether it's a necessary thing. It's generally a sign of poor design.

Typical workarounds is putting the special behaviour for the class you are checking for into a virtual function on the base class or perhaps introducing something like a [visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) where you can introduce specific behaviour for subclasses without changing the interface (except for adding the visitor acceptance interface of course).

As pointed out dynamic_cast doesn't come for free. A simple and consistently performing hack that handles most (but not all cases) is basically adding an enum representing all the possible types your class can have and check whether you got the right one.

```
if(old->getType() == BOX) {
   Box* box = static_cast<Box*>(old);
   // Do something box specific
}
```

This is not good oo design, but it can be a workaround and its cost is more or less only a virtual function call. It also works regardless of RTTI is enabled or not.

Note that this approach doesn't support multiple levels of inheritance so if you're not careful you might end with code looking like this:

```
// Here we have a SpecialBox class that inherits Box, since it has its own type
// we must check for both BOX or SPECIAL_BOX
if(old->getType() == BOX || old->getType() == SPECIAL_BOX) {
   Box* box = static_cast<Box*>(old);
   // Do something box specific
}
```

Comment: class have to have at least one virtual method for this to work

Comment: That's generally the case when you do a "instanceof" check

Comment: If you have to use instanceof, there is, in most cases, something wrong with your design.

Comment: Don't forget that dynamic_cast is an operation with big cost.

Comment: There are many examples of reasonable uses of dynamic type testing. It's not usually preferred, but it has a place.
(Otherwise, why would it or its equivalent appear in every major OO-language: C++, Java, Python, etc.?)

Comment: @mslot Would you consider exception-handling in Java a case of `instanceof` being flawed design? For example, since `FileNotFoundException` and `EOFException` is `IOException` could we use `if (exception instanceof EOFException)` in catch block and still not have design suffer?

Comment: I would catch both at IOException level if they do not need to be handled diffently. If they need to be handled diffently, then I would add a catch block for each exception.

Comment: In `if(v != 0)` the `!= 0` part does nothing but littering the source code.

Comment: As I wrote elsewhere about the visitor pattern: It doesn't solve anything if the decision has to be made only upon the type of the object that is accepting the visitor. 
The remaining workarounds you suggest are ugly.

Comment: This business everyone has installed in their heads from pretenders that dynamic_cast is "generally a sign of poor design" need to rethink how the language was developed. I'm pretty sure Stroustrup had his reasons and it most likely much more in the know about how and why than any pretenders...

Comment: @mcoder Stroustrup added RTTI because users were demanding it for serialization libraries, IIRC.

Comment: Sometimes it's something wrong with a design, but not something wrong with your design. Sometimes it's something wrong with the design of a library. For example when writing a QT based server that deals with both TCP and bluetooth you find that for some reason QBluetoothSocket is not a descendent of QAbstractSocket even though once connected it offers much the same functionality.

Comment: "It's generally a sign of poor design." Not really. It's usually sign of being in the process of debugging something or trying to understand existing code  through experimentation or not being able to adapt existing code when adding functionality. But it really needs an excuse, I agree thus far 

Answer (score 48):

Depending on what you want to do you could do this:

```
template<typename Base, typename T>
inline bool instanceof(const T*) {
    return std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value;
}
```

Use:

```
if (instanceof<BaseClass>(ptr)) { ... }
```

However, this purely operates on the types as known by the compiler.

**Edit:**

This code should work for polymorphic pointers:

```
template<typename Base, typename T>
inline bool instanceof(const T *ptr) {
    return dynamic_cast<const Base*>(ptr) != nullptr;
}
```

Example: http://cpp.sh/6qir

Comment: Elegant and well done solution. +1
But be careful to get the correct pointer. Not valid for polymorphic pointer ?

Comment: What if we deferenced the pointer when using this function?  Would it then work for polymorphic pointers?

Comment: No this only operates on the types as known to the compiler. Won't work with polymorphic pointers, no matter if you derefernece or not. I'll add something that might work in that case though.

Comment: I have modified your example to write a version of this method which uses references instead of pointers: http://cpp.sh/8owv

Comment: Why has the target type of the dynamic cast "const"?

Comment: @user1056903 No real reason other than keeping it cleanly const.

Comment: @panzi what you mean by `types as known by the compiler`??

Comment: @thiagoh It doesn't look at rtti (the 2nd version does). So it only says `true` if you could see just by looking at that source line if `T` is a subclass of `Base` anyway.

Answer (score 15):

## Instanceof implementation without dynamic_cast

I think this question is still relevant today. Using the C++11 standard you are now able to implement a `instanceof` function without using `dynamic_cast` like this:

```
if (dynamic_cast<B*>(aPtr) != nullptr) {
  // aPtr is instance of B
} else {
  // aPtr is NOT instance of B
}
```

But you're still reliant on `RTTI` support. So here is my solution for this problem depending on some Macros and Metaprogramming Magic. The only drawback imho is that this approach does **not** work for *multiple inheritance*.

**InstanceOfMacros.h**

```
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeindex>

#define _EMPTY_BASE_TYPE_DECL() using BaseTypes = std::tuple<>;
#define _BASE_TYPE_DECL(Class, BaseClass) \
  using BaseTypes = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::tuple<BaseClass>(), Class::BaseTypes()));
#define _INSTANCE_OF_DECL_BODY(Class)                                 \
  static const std::set<std::type_index> baseTypeContainer;           \
  virtual bool instanceOfHelper(const std::type_index &_tidx) {       \
    if (std::type_index(typeid(ThisType)) == _tidx) return true;      \
    if (std::tuple_size<BaseTypes>::value == 0) return false;         \
    return baseTypeContainer.find(_tidx) != baseTypeContainer.end();  \
  }                                                                   \
  template <typename... T>                                            \
  static std::set<std::type_index> getTypeIndexes(std::tuple<T...>) { \
    return std::set<std::type_index>{std::type_index(typeid(T))...};  \
  }

#define INSTANCE_OF_SUB_DECL(Class, BaseClass) \
 protected:                                    \
  using ThisType = Class;                      \
  _BASE_TYPE_DECL(Class, BaseClass)            \
  _INSTANCE_OF_DECL_BODY(Class)

#define INSTANCE_OF_BASE_DECL(Class)                                                    \
 protected:                                                                             \
  using ThisType = Class;                                                               \
  _EMPTY_BASE_TYPE_DECL()                                                               \
  _INSTANCE_OF_DECL_BODY(Class)                                                         \
 public:                                                                                \
  template <typename Of>                                                                \
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Class, Of>::value, bool>::type instanceOf() { \
    return instanceOfHelper(std::type_index(typeid(Of)));                               \
  }

#define INSTANCE_OF_IMPL(Class) \
  const std::set<std::type_index> Class::baseTypeContainer = Class::getTypeIndexes(Class::BaseTypes());
```

## Demo

You can then use this stuff (**with caution**) as follows:

**DemoClassHierarchy.hpp***

```
#include "InstanceOfMacros.h"

struct A {
  virtual ~A() {}
  INSTANCE_OF_BASE_DECL(A)
};
INSTANCE_OF_IMPL(A)

struct B : public A {
  virtual ~B() {}
  INSTANCE_OF_SUB_DECL(B, A)
};
INSTANCE_OF_IMPL(B)

struct C : public A {
  virtual ~C() {}
  INSTANCE_OF_SUB_DECL(C, A)
};
INSTANCE_OF_IMPL(C)

struct D : public C {
  virtual ~D() {}
  INSTANCE_OF_SUB_DECL(D, C)
};
INSTANCE_OF_IMPL(D)
```

The following code presents a small demo to verify rudimentary the correct behavior.

**InstanceOfDemo.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "DemoClassHierarchy.hpp"

int main() {
  A *a2aPtr = new A;
  A *a2bPtr = new B;
  std::shared_ptr<A> a2cPtr(new C);
  C *c2dPtr = new D;
  std::unique_ptr<A> a2dPtr(new D);

  std::cout << "a2aPtr->instanceOf<A>(): expected=1, value=" << a2aPtr->instanceOf<A>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a2aPtr->instanceOf<B>(): expected=0, value=" << a2aPtr->instanceOf<B>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a2aPtr->instanceOf<C>(): expected=0, value=" << a2aPtr->instanceOf<C>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a2aPtr->instanceOf<D>(): expected=0, value=" << a2aPtr->instanceOf<D>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a2bPtr->instanceOf<A>(): expected=1, value=" << a2bPtr->instanceOf<A>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a2bPtr->instanceOf<B>(): expected=1, value=" << a2bPtr->instanceOf<B>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a2bPtr->instanceOf<C>(): expected=0, value=" << a2bPtr->instanceOf<C>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a2bPtr->instanceOf<D>(): expected=0, value=" << a2bPtr->instanceOf<D>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a2cPtr->instanceOf<A>(): expected=1, value=" << a2cPtr->instanceOf<A>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a2cPtr->instanceOf<B>(): expected=0, value=" << a2cPtr->instanceOf<B>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a2cPtr->instanceOf<C>(): expected=1, value=" << a2cPtr->instanceOf<C>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a2cPtr->instanceOf<D>(): expected=0, value=" << a2cPtr->instanceOf<D>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "c2dPtr->instanceOf<A>(): expected=1, value=" << c2dPtr->instanceOf<A>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "c2dPtr->instanceOf<B>(): expected=0, value=" << c2dPtr->instanceOf<B>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "c2dPtr->instanceOf<C>(): expected=1, value=" << c2dPtr->instanceOf<C>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "c2dPtr->instanceOf<D>(): expected=1, value=" << c2dPtr->instanceOf<D>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a2dPtr->instanceOf<A>(): expected=1, value=" << a2dPtr->instanceOf<A>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a2dPtr->instanceOf<B>(): expected=0, value=" << a2dPtr->instanceOf<B>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a2dPtr->instanceOf<C>(): expected=1, value=" << a2dPtr->instanceOf<C>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a2dPtr->instanceOf<D>(): expected=1, value=" << a2dPtr->instanceOf<D>() << std::endl;

  delete a2aPtr;
  delete a2bPtr;
  delete c2dPtr;

  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
a2aPtr->instanceOf<A>(): expected=1, value=1
a2aPtr->instanceOf<B>(): expected=0, value=0
a2aPtr->instanceOf<C>(): expected=0, value=0
a2aPtr->instanceOf<D>(): expected=0, value=0

a2bPtr->instanceOf<A>(): expected=1, value=1
a2bPtr->instanceOf<B>(): expected=1, value=1
a2bPtr->instanceOf<C>(): expected=0, value=0
a2bPtr->instanceOf<D>(): expected=0, value=0

a2cPtr->instanceOf<A>(): expected=1, value=1
a2cPtr->instanceOf<B>(): expected=0, value=0
a2cPtr->instanceOf<C>(): expected=1, value=1
a2cPtr->instanceOf<D>(): expected=0, value=0

c2dPtr->instanceOf<A>(): expected=1, value=1
c2dPtr->instanceOf<B>(): expected=0, value=0
c2dPtr->instanceOf<C>(): expected=1, value=1
c2dPtr->instanceOf<D>(): expected=1, value=1

a2dPtr->instanceOf<A>(): expected=1, value=1
a2dPtr->instanceOf<B>(): expected=0, value=0
a2dPtr->instanceOf<C>(): expected=1, value=1
a2dPtr->instanceOf<D>(): expected=1, value=1
```

## Performance

The most interesting question which now arises is, if this evil stuff is more efficient than the usage of `dynamic_cast`. Therefore I've written a very basic performance measurement app.

**InstanceOfPerformance.cpp**

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "DemoClassHierarchy.hpp"

template <typename Base, typename Derived, typename Duration>
Duration instanceOfMeasurement(unsigned _loopCycles) {
  auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  volatile bool isInstanceOf = false;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < _loopCycles; ++i) {
    Base *ptr = new Derived;
    isInstanceOf = ptr->template instanceOf<Derived>();
    delete ptr;
  }
  auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  return std::chrono::duration_cast<Duration>(end - start);
}

template <typename Base, typename Derived, typename Duration>
Duration dynamicCastMeasurement(unsigned _loopCycles) {
  auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  volatile bool isInstanceOf = false;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < _loopCycles; ++i) {
    Base *ptr = new Derived;
    isInstanceOf = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(ptr) != nullptr;
    delete ptr;
  }
  auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  return std::chrono::duration_cast<Duration>(end - start);
}

int main() {
  unsigned testCycles = 10000000;
  std::string unit = " us";
  using DType = std::chrono::microseconds;

  std::cout << "InstanceOf performance(A->D)  : " << instanceOfMeasurement<A, D, DType>(testCycles).count() << unit
            << std::endl;
  std::cout << "InstanceOf performance(A->C)  : " << instanceOfMeasurement<A, C, DType>(testCycles).count() << unit
            << std::endl;
  std::cout << "InstanceOf performance(A->B)  : " << instanceOfMeasurement<A, B, DType>(testCycles).count() << unit
            << std::endl;
  std::cout << "InstanceOf performance(A->A)  : " << instanceOfMeasurement<A, A, DType>(testCycles).count() << unit
            << "\n"
            << std::endl;
  std::cout << "DynamicCast performance(A->D) : " << dynamicCastMeasurement<A, D, DType>(testCycles).count() << unit
            << std::endl;
  std::cout << "DynamicCast performance(A->C) : " << dynamicCastMeasurement<A, C, DType>(testCycles).count() << unit
            << std::endl;
  std::cout << "DynamicCast performance(A->B) : " << dynamicCastMeasurement<A, B, DType>(testCycles).count() << unit
            << std::endl;
  std::cout << "DynamicCast performance(A->A) : " << dynamicCastMeasurement<A, A, DType>(testCycles).count() << unit
            << "\n"
            << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The results vary and are essentially based on the degree of compiler optimization. Compiling the performance measurement program using `g++ -std=c++11 -O0 -o instanceof-performance InstanceOfPerformance.cpp` the output on my local machine was:

```
InstanceOf performance(A->D)  : 699638 us
InstanceOf performance(A->C)  : 642157 us
InstanceOf performance(A->B)  : 671399 us
InstanceOf performance(A->A)  : 626193 us

DynamicCast performance(A->D) : 754937 us
DynamicCast performance(A->C) : 706766 us
DynamicCast performance(A->B) : 751353 us
DynamicCast performance(A->A) : 676853 us
```

Mhm, this result was very sobering, because the timings demonstrates that the new approach is not much faster compared to the `dynamic_cast` approach. It is even less efficient for the special test case which tests if a pointer of `A` is an instance of`A`. **BUT** the tide turns by tuning our binary using compiler otpimization. The respective compiler command is `g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -o instanceof-performance InstanceOfPerformance.cpp`. The result on my local machine was amazing:

```
InstanceOf performance(A->D)  : 3035 us
InstanceOf performance(A->C)  : 5030 us
InstanceOf performance(A->B)  : 5250 us
InstanceOf performance(A->A)  : 3021 us

DynamicCast performance(A->D) : 666903 us
DynamicCast performance(A->C) : 698567 us
DynamicCast performance(A->B) : 727368 us
DynamicCast performance(A->A) : 3098 us
```

If you are not reliant on multiple inheritance, are no opponent of good old C macros, RTTI and template metaprogramming and are not too lazy to add some small instructions to the classes of your class hierarchy, then this approach can boost your application a little bit with respect to its performance, if you often end up with checking the instance of a pointer. **But use it with caution**. There is no warranty for the correctness of this approach.

*Note: All demos were compiled using `clang (Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2))` under macOS Sierra on a MacBook Pro Mid 2012.*

**Edit:**
I've also tested the performance on a Linux machine using `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609`. On this platform the perfomance benefit was not so significant as on macOs with clang.

**Output (without compiler optimization):**

```
InstanceOf performance(A->D)  : 390768 us
InstanceOf performance(A->C)  : 333994 us
InstanceOf performance(A->B)  : 334596 us
InstanceOf performance(A->A)  : 300959 us

DynamicCast performance(A->D) : 331942 us
DynamicCast performance(A->C) : 303715 us
DynamicCast performance(A->B) : 400262 us
DynamicCast performance(A->A) : 324942 us
```

**Output (with compiler optimization):**

```
InstanceOf performance(A->D)  : 209501 us
InstanceOf performance(A->C)  : 208727 us
InstanceOf performance(A->B)  : 207815 us
InstanceOf performance(A->A)  : 197953 us

DynamicCast performance(A->D) : 259417 us
DynamicCast performance(A->C) : 256203 us
DynamicCast performance(A->B) : 261202 us
DynamicCast performance(A->A) : 193535 us
```

Comment: Well thought-out answer! I'm glad you provided the timings. This was an interesting read.

Answer (score 2):

`dynamic_cast` is known to be inefficient. It traverses up the inheritance hierarchy, and *it is* the only solution if you have multiple levels of inheritance, and need to check if an object is an instance of any one of the types in its type hierarchy.

But if a more limited form of `instanceof` that only checks if an object is exactly the type you specify, suffices for your needs, the function below would be a lot more efficient:

```
template<typename T, typename K>
inline bool isType(const K &k) {
    return typeid(T).hash_code() == typeid(k).hash_code();
}
```

Here's an example of how you'd invoke the function above:

```
DerivedA k;
Base *p = &k;

cout << boolalpha << isType<DerivedA>(*p) << endl;  // true
cout << boolalpha << isType<DerivedB>(*p) << endl;  // false
```

You'd specify template type `A` (as the type you're checking for), and pass in the object you want to test as the argument (from which template type `K` would be inferred).

Comment: The standard does not require hash_code to be unique for different types, so this is unreliable.

Comment: Isn't typeid(T) itself comparable with equality, so no reliance on the hashcode is needed?

Comment: I have found out that dynamic_cast is BS. If you had  int i; A *a = (A*)&i; dynamic_cast doesnt return NULL. And if you had T t; A *a = (A*)&t; where T is derived from A. dynamic cast also doesn't return NULL. And of course a base class cannot be an instanceof a derived class.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include<typeinfo.h>

template<class T>
void fun(T a)
{
  if(typeid(T) == typeid(int))
  {
     //Do something
     cout<<"int";
  }
  else if(typeid(T) == typeid(float))
  {
     //Do Something else
     cout<<"float";
  }
}

void main()
 {
      fun(23);
      fun(90.67f);
 }
```

Comment: This is a really bad example. Why not use overloading, that is cheaper?

Comment: The main problem is that it fails to answer the question. `instanceof` queries the dynamic type, but in this answer the dynamic and static type always correspond.

Comment: @HHH you answer is way way off the question being asked!