# C++ dynamic_cast vs typeid for class comparison

Tags: c++, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [C++ equivalent of instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500493/c-equivalent-of-instanceof)

I was wondering what the difference between `dynamic_cast` and `typeid` is in regards to just class comparison (aside from `dynamic_cast` allowing access to the subclass's methods and `typeid` only being useful for class comparison). I found a two year old StackOverflow asking the same question:
[C++ equivalent of java's instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500493/c-equivalent-of-instanceof). However, it is two years old and I did not want to necro an old post (and I am unsure when `typeid` came out), so I thought to re-ask the same question with a slight difference.

Basically, I have class `A` and class `B`, which are both subclasses of abstract class `C`. Class `C` is being taken in as a parameter to a method and I want to determine if class `C` is really class `A` or class `B`. Both `typeid` and `dynamic_cast` work properly so this is more of a question of best practice/performance. I am guessing :

```
A* test = dynamic_cast<A*> someClassCVar
if (test != 0) { //it is of class A }
```

OR

```
if (typeid(someClassCVar) == typeid(A)) {
   //it is of class A
}
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, I forgot to include this bit of information. The ActiveMQ CMS documentation states to use `dynamic_cast`, but I think that is only because it assumes the user will want to access methods specific to the subclass. To me, it seems that `typeid` would be better performance if only a class comparison is needed:
https://activemq.apache.org/components/cms/overview

Comment: I'd say the `dynamic_cast` is to be preferred, but I have no sources to back my opinion.

Comment: `dynamic_cast<A*>someClassCVar`  will return non-null if `someClassCVar` is a pointer to `A` or any of `A`'s descendants. `typeid(someClassCVar) == typeid(A)` is true only if `someClassCVar` is A type. So 2 pieces of your code are not equivalent.

Comment: Usually it's a design smell if a C++ program needs to know which child class a parent pointer points to. You should at least step back for 15 minutes and look at your design.

Comment: What, precisely, is your question?

Comment: What is the best C++ practice when only doing a class comparison?

Comment: There are many with the opinion that, if you have to use RTTI, your design is flawed. It makes adding new types difficult, since if you would add a new class D, which inherits from C, you would have to add code to any method which uses RTTI on objects of type C. RTTI should only be used for debug information, and maybe for some kinds of plugin architecture.

Comment: @Jon: unlike Java (I think), C++ has an ISO Standard that references what is or is not available. `dynamic_cast` and `typeid` are reference by the C++ Standard that came out in 1998.

Comment: The design is... special because the higher ups are trying to keep C++ and Java code as similar as possible. Also, I updated my question to less confusing/similar to the one I linked to.

Comment: *because the higher ups are trying to keep C++ and Java* you are in for a world of hurt. **Don't**. Each languages has its own idioms, and trying to emulate one language with another is just a recipe for disaster. Explain it to your higher ups, they need see the light. What you are asking for is leaning toward reflection, which C++ does not support.

Comment: The best way to deal with this, would be to move the class specific code out of that method into the respective classes A or B. Use some patterns like the command-pattern or the visitor-pattern etc. to do this in a clean way, which just works fine in Java aswell.

Comment: This answer helped a lot. Thank you. It's shame it's closed as duplicate. It isn't. The "original" one worths nothing.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is an important difference between the two methods:

```
if(A* test = dynamic_cast<A*>(&someClassCVar)) {
    // someClassCVar is A or publicly derived from A
}
```

Whereas:

```
if(typeid(someClassCVar) == typeid(A)) {
   // someClassCVar is of class A, not a derived class
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. So if we do not care if it is A or a subclass of A for some reason, which would be better?

Comment: @Jon: obviously the first one ;)

Comment: `dynamic_cast<>` then, since you're only interested in the interface of `A` and don't care how it's implemented.

Answer (score 2):

it depends if post type identification processing needs a pointer on A or not.

cheking typeid will surely be faster (since they're compiler generated constant identifiers) but won't provide any A instance to manipulate so will oblige you to perform a dynamic_cast to get a A instance.

Comment: ... or static_cast if C is non-virtual base class for A and B