# How to check the Object Type in c++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

For example we have an Animal class ,and we created some other class such as Lion class,Tiger class,etc. I have made a list of the Animal class and I want to transverse the list and process the list according to the type of the class of the every member in the list.

```
Class Animal
Class Tiger :: public Animal{}
Class Lion :: public Animal{}
list<Animal> l;
Tiger T;
Lion L;
l.push_back(T); l.push_back(L);
if the top member of the list is Tiger print"ITs a tiger"
else print"something"
```

Simply, I want to check the type of the instance created.  I don't know how to do it.

Comment: If you want to check the type your design seems wrong and You should consider revisiting it.To know the type, You can use `typeinfo` of `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: list<Animal> is wrong for this, because of slicing problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Comment: You need to re-visit the design. What you probably need is virtual methods. An extension to this is the visitor pattern.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ equivalent of instanceof](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500493/c-equivalent-of-instanceof)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) and it's not good coding practice.

This being said, if you absolutely want to know a class' type, you can do

```
if (typeid(myanimal) == typeid(Tiger)) {
    // Do something tiger-like
}
```

What I would recommend in your case is to have a common interface to all `Animal`, for instance a `sayHello()` method. You would have

```
class Animal {
    void sayHello() = 0;
    // Other things
}
```

In `Tiger` this would be

```
Tiger::sayHello() {
    cout << "Hello I'm a Tiger!" << endl;
}
```

Then, from your `vector<Animal*>` (you need to use pointers) just call

```
myAnimal->sayHello();
```

Comment: vector<Animal> simply store Animals and can not hold ex. Tiger. You have to store it as a ptr like structure

Comment: Please no vector of pointers. There is no ownership semantics to the pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the type (`typeid`), yes, but you don't need to.

You can just hold a `std::list<std::unique_ptr<Animal> >` and have a `virtual` method in `Animal`.  This way you're taking advantage of polymorphism.

```
class Animal
{
public: 
    virtual void print() = 0;
};
class Tiger : Animal
{
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "I'm a tiger"; }
};

Animal* pA = new Tiger;
pA->print(); // prints tiger
```

Answer (score 0):

use dynamic_cast and check whether result is valid. 
But!!!!!!! You it is usually a bad practice: in your case it is better in the base class to declare virtual function 
virtual std::string printMe() const = 0; 
and implement it in each class.