# What is an equivalent to instanceof in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, casting, mfc, instance

How can I check the class type in c++?
In Java I used `instanceof`.

I prefer not to use dynamic cast, but only classic c++.
Is there any way?

**Clarification:**
It isn't a duplicate of [another question in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500493), since I asked how can I find it without using of `dynamic_cast`. In the other question, the answer was to use it. Please don't mark it as a duplicated.

Comment: What do you mean by classic C++ if not dynamic_cast? And what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I mean, for `dynamic_cast` you need use `std::...`. For any reason I have not to use it. I created base class and some derive ones. When I get an object I want to do an operation associated to the specific derived class, but I got it in a loop so it is defined as the base one. In Java, by `instanceof` I could know which type is it. But in C++ with no use of `dynamic_cast`, how can I know?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is a language feature, not a library feature. It really sounds like you just want a virtual function that the derived class overrides.

Comment: You right, but I want to know it without using of virtual function. Only to check type.

Comment: Well, checking the type is generally considered bad design in the first place. There's a reason C++ doesn't have it and you wouldn't need to check the type and do something based on it with a virtual function in place.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: you want to check the type, but you don't want to use `dynamic_cast`, which is the way C++ checks the type.  (In Java, `instanceof` is just a semantic wrapper for the equivalent of `dynamic_cast` in C++.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, you understand perfectly. I have a problem in use of `std` namespace and search for aletrnative way.  
If I wrote it in Java, I wouldn't have this problem. Java is a strong language.

Comment: @Aharon: If you remove `Object` and the other library classes in Java, it's not a strong language either. The stuff _outside_ `std::` is mostly there for C compatibility, and C is not an OO language. So asking for OO features, and restricting yourself to the non-OO subset of C++ is plain dumb.

Comment: @Aharon First, `dynamic_cast` is *not* in `std`.  It's a keyword.  Second, as MSalters says, removing `std` from C++ is the equivalent of removing the package `java` from Java.  And what would Java be without `java.lang.Object` or `java.lang.String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to check class type without RTTI or it's home brew substitution. If application compiled without RTTI information about type is not stored anywhere.