# instanceof equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, instanceof

I'm creating a 2D game in C++ that uses levels made out of tiles. The world class has an `add(WorldObject* o)` function that can both accept a tile or an entity such as an enemy. Both the `Tile` and the `Entity` class are derived from `WorldObject`. In every case, the object should be added to the `entities` list; but if it is a tile, it should also be added to the `tiles` list.

World.h

```
class World {
private:
    list<WorldObject*> content;
    list<Tile*> tiles;
public:
    void add(WorldObject*);
}
```

World.cpp

```
void World::add(WorldObject* o) {
    content.push_back(o);
    if(*o instanceof Tile) //What do I need to put here?
        tiles.push_back(o);
}
```

How do I check whether an object has a specific type in C++? It's nothing about typecasting and virtual functions and things like that because I don't want to invoke functions to the object at this time; I just need to add it to a separate list if it has a certain type.
In Java, I can do `if(instance instanceof Class)`. How can I do this in C++?

Comment: `dynamic_cast<>`should well serve for your purposes, doesn't it? If you can statiaclly bind, use `static_cast<>`.

Comment: See the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500493/c-equivalent-of-instanceof?rq=1

Comment: Why not two functions, `void add(Tile*)` and `void add(Entity*)`? Is the type of the object passed to `add` not available any more?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: But as I don't wanna do a typecast. I just want to CHECK if it has the type, not CONVERT it.

Comment: You need a cast since you have a `WorldObject*` and want a `Entity*` or a `Tile*` (to append to either list).

Comment: There's a significantly cleaner way to do this with `typeid`, I will post my answer shortly.

Comment: Can't you make add a virtual function and then define their respective meanings in the entity and tile classes?

Comment: @dyp see my answer, same vein I think.

Comment: I suggest rather than duplicating the tiles list in the entity list that you rethink how you are doing this.  I would be loathe to duplicate stored data in this fashion.

Comment: How would you do it then? My intention is to have quick access to a list with only the world's tiles and a little higher memory usage should be way better than a significantly higher CPU usage that results from going through the list and doing a check on every object it contains to see wether it is a tile.

Comment: @RichardChambers exactly, tell the OP this should be a design pattern question and confirm my answer for him!

Comment: @cmbasnett or design patterns! If you need to choose between base classes you've usually abstracted too much away!

Comment: You are thinking of the implementation rather than the problem domain and you are using procedural thinking rather than object oriented thinking and laying yourself open to more and more complexity.  I just recognize the anti-pattern since it is the same kind of mistake I have made in the past until I finally got enough education and reading and thinking to recognize the error when I was making it.  It usually comes from crafting something incrementally and ad hoc without a good architecture and then trying to get by without refactoring and rearchitecting.

Comment: @RichardChambers *cough* http://stackoverflow.com/a/27595177/2112028

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `dynamic_cast` will check to see if you can downcast `o` to `Tile`. If you can, it will return a valid `Tile*`, else it will return a null `Tile*`:

```
void World::add(WorldObject* o) {
    content.push_back(o);
    if (Tile* t = dynamic_cast<Tile*>(o)) {
        tiles.push_back(t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can only infer the dynamic type of an object at run-time if the object is polymorphic, ie has at least one `virtual` function member.  A `virtual` destructor will also do for this matter.  (Actually, talking about a “dynamic type” doesn't make much sense if nothing is `virtual` anyway.)

Then you can try a `dynamic_cast` as an `instanceof` equivalence.  Where you would have written

```java
void f(Base base) {
    if (base instanceof Derived) {
        Derived derived = (Derived) base;
        // use derived
    }
}
```

in Java, you would write

```cpp
void
f(Base& base)
{
  if (Derived * derived_ptr = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(&base))
    {
      // use derived_ptr
    }
}
```

in C++.  A `dynamic_cast` to a pointer type will simply return a `nullptr` (which evaluates to `false`) if the object is not of the right type so it is usually seen inside an  `if`.  A `dynamic_cast` to a reference, however, would throw an exception so you should only use it if you are sure that the object actually is of that type.

I should add that the C++ example will only be valid if `Derived` is actually derived from `Base`.  Otherwise the check would have been rather pointless anyway.  Note however that you cannot restore the type of an object through a `void *` pointer.  It makes sense if you think about it because that `void *` might actually point to a random collection of bytes that has nothing whatsoever to extract a type from.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
if(dynamic_cast<Tile*>(o))
```

This works because `dynamic_cast` on a pointer returns null if the type is not compatible.  And of course, a null pointer is "falsy", so the check will fail.  If `o` is in fact a `Tile`, a non-null `Tile*` will result, and the check will succeed.

Answer (score 1):

This should be an answer, but it may not be /the/ answer. What you're doing is awful. You will have something like:

```
void addObject(Object* ob) {
    if(ob->isA()) { doA(ob); }
    if(ob->isB()) { doB(ob); }
    if(ob->isC()) { doC(ob); }
    genericObjectStuff(ob);
}
```

This is an "antipattern" because it is bad, it means for each derived you have (in your case `Tile` is CURRENTLY the only one) you'll have to come back to this function and add any special behaviour.

There are two fixes (that depend on what the objects in play are like)

**1) Virtual functions:**

```
void addObject(Object* ob) {
    ob->doSpecificThingYouNeedToDo(this);
    genericObjectStuff(ob);
}
```

Where `doSpecificThingYouNeedToDo` will `doA(this);` inside if it is an A, do B if it is a B.... thus you write what it does when it is added where you define the class! Much better!

**2) You've abstracted away too much!**

If I give you a `DrivableThing` you know you can do whatever it means to be a `DrivableThing` to it, you are not given that it is a `Truck` say (which IS A `DrivableThing`) so you cannot `loadCargo` on the drivable thing because it might not be a truck!

So a function that loads cargo can only accept `Truck`s, or some other type that is drivable and loadable. It'd be wrong to have a generic function that loaded trucks, but also put pizzas on the back of motorbikes (Delivery task also!)

This is the opposite of 1, rather than adding the functionality to the derived classes, you want different `addObject`s that accept the specific object only. Because they require this information, so you currently have:

```
void loadUpCargo(DrivableThing* thing) {
    if(thing->isPizzaBike()) { thing->addPizzas(whatever); }
    if(thing->isTruck()) { thing->addCrates(whatever); }
    thing->driveOff(); //we can always drive off DrivableThings
}
```

You can change this to:

```
void loadUpCargo(Truck* truck) {
    truck->addCrates(whatever);
    truck->driveOff(); 
}
void loadUpCargo(PizzaBike* bike) {
    bike->addPizza(whatever);
    bike->driveOff();
}
```

Much better!

The classic example of this is "Animal class has an Eat method" "Bananas are Eatable, a Monkey is an Animal" but having an Animal and an Eatable wont stop you feeding Grass to a Monkey because you've abstracted the information away!

Comment: I think you got my intention entirely wrong. I do know what virtual functions are and when to use them. I just want to have a list with everything the level contains and an additional list with just the tiles for faster collision checking.

Comment: @Rapti this isn't about virtual functions at all. It's object patterns.

Comment: Sorting things by type for performance reasons is actually one of the rare valid uses of run-time type inference (RTII) so the OP's desire does seem legitimate to me.  If you can already sort at the place where to objects are created (so there type is known) then that's of course even better but I wouldn't break up an otherwise clean API to expose this optimization / implementation detail just to avoid a single use of RTTI deeply inside somewhere it belongs.

Comment: I added that comment when you hadn't added 2) yet. But still, my code it doesn't match your animal example because absolutely any WorldObject can be added to the world; it's not a monkey just eating bananas. I just want to do one extra task if it has a certain type (add it to the tile list if it is a tile). Creating a separate add(Tile* t) function wouldn't make much sense because if the tile is passed on as a WorldObject*, it wouldn't be added to the tiles list.

Comment: @Rapti here the animal is your tiles list, and you are trying to make sure only Bananas get added to it - QED

Comment: And if I create an `addTile(Tile* t)` function, what prevents someone from passing a `WorldObject*` that actually points to a tile to the `addTile(WorldObject* o)` function, resulting in the tile not being added to the tiles list?

Comment: @5gon12eder either way there's a vtable lookup, and you'd be relying on compiler optimisations with dynamic_cast (think about a dynamic cast, it has to get the typeid of the two objects, then see if it's a valid base, which is a graph search, at best a tree....) with a vtable there's much less than that, if the compiler does it at all. With the second one the overhead is compile time due to overloading, __MOST IMPORTANT POINT__ Optimising early is the root of all evil. Also how many tiles would he have to add and how little work would they do if this optimisation got his FPS up from 30 to 60?

Comment: @Rapti don't have an `addTile(WorldObject*)` now I know you typoed for just `add(WorldObject*)`, if the caller doesn't know if it's a tile or a worldobject then you want the first method. Callbacks are one of the main uses of the pattern (have the added WorldObject that is actually a Tile callback the World and add itself to the tiles list, a method called `onAddedToWorld(World*)` would be perfect.

Comment: Oh, strangely I can no longer fix the typo. But whatever, so you're telling me to separate by using virtual functions? Does this not mean I would be calling a world function with my object that does a call to my object so it adds itself to the world rather than adding it directly to the world? I think that would be a design pattern much worse than you accuse mine to be.

Comment: @Rapti read 1 again. Also I'm done with this, I can't force help on you and I've wasted enough time. Good luck - you'll need it.