# How do I ask if an object belong to a class x?

Tags: c++, object

So I've got Shape.h, Rectangle.h, Circle.h and main.cpp.

Shape.h got:

```
class Shape{
public:
    Shape() {};
    ~Shape() { cout << "Destroy Shape."; };

    virtual double getArea() = 0;
    virtual double getCircumference() = 0;
};
```

Rectangle and Circle their respective code.

Now in main.cpp I do

```
Shape* newRectangle= new Rectangle(4, 8);
Shape* newCircle= new Circle(10);
```

All fine and dandy so far. Here's where I'm stumped. I know what I have to do, I just don't know HOW to do it.

I'm trying to write a function that checks if a Shape* Object belongs to Circle or not.

It goes something like this

```
if Shape* object belongs to Object-Type Circle, then
cout << "It's a Circle, bruh!";
else
cout << "Ain't a circle, yo!";
```

I started after googling with that:

```
void check(Shape & object){
    Circle& checkObject = dynamic_cast<Circle&>(object);

}
```

The function in main will be called via:

```
check(*newRectangle);
check(*newCircle);
```

But I haven't got a clue how to go on :(. Any help and explanation is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500493/c-equivalent-of-instanceof

Comment: Make class `Shape` polymorphic. That means it has at least one virtual function. Usually the destructor is made virtual. Then you can use the C++ RTTI functionality, `typeid` and `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Make `~Shape()` `virtual`.  That ensures `delete shp;` deletes whole class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by dynamically casting the `Shape` pointer to a pointer of desired type, and checking for `nullptr`:

```
if (dynamic_cast<Circle*>(object)) {
    cout << "It's a Circle, bruh!";
}
```

This requires that Runtime Type Information is turned on, and that your object has at least one virtual function (it does).

**Note 1:** if you have to do something like that, see if you could change your design so that you wouldn't have to do this. For example, you could apply a multiple dispatch pattern, such as *Visitor*, to avoid this check:

```
struct ShapeVisitor {
    virtual ~ShapeVisitor() {}
    virtual void visitCircle(const Circle* circle);
    virtual void visitRectangle(const Rectangle* rectangle);
};

class Shape{
public:
    Shape() {};
    virtual ~Shape() { cout << "Destroy Shape."; };

    virtual double getArea() = 0;
    virtual double getCircumference() = 0;
    virtual void Accept(const ShapeVisitor& visitor) = 0;
};

struct Circle : public Shape {
    virtual void Accept(const ShapeVisitor& visitor) {
        visitor.visitCircle(this);
    }
};

struct Rectangle : public Shape {
    virtual void Accept(const ShapeVisitor& visitor) {
        visitor.visitRectangle(this);
    }
};
```

Now you can print the kind of shape you see like this:

```
struct PrintTypeVisitor : public ShapeVisitor {
    virtual void visitCircle(const Circle* circle) {
        cout << "It's a Circle, bruh!";
    }
    virtual void visitRectangle(const Rectangle* rectangle) {
        cout << "It's a Rectangle, bruh!";
    }
}
...
PrintTypeVisitor v;
Shape* object = ...
object.Accept(v); // This prints dynamic type of the object
```

**Note 2:** You need to make `Shape`'s destructor virtual.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking about something link that. Null or nullpointer. Hmm...gonna try it. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the destructor on the base class need to be virtual for deletion through a base class pointer to work correctly?

Comment: @JamesAdkison Yes, thanks for the comment! I copied OP's code, but missed the non-`virtual` destructor.

Comment: Thank you, this solution is elegant, but not what I'm trying to understand right now. I'm trying to understand how http://pastebin.com/BxjEBfg9 works. Once I get that, I'll try your method :). It doesn't help me learning new methods while not understanding others.

Comment: @NoCanDo It works because the compiler squirrels away an extra piece of information with each object, which can be used to see if it is OK to cast through a base pointer (i.e. a `Share`) to a subclass (i.e. a `Circle` or a `Rectangle`). `dynamic_cast` operation checks this extra piece of information, and either produces a correct pointer if the cast is valid, or returns `nullptr` if the cast would be invalid.

Answer (score 6):

1. Try to avoid logic based on derived types. Use `virtual` member functions whenever you can.

   ```
   class Shape {
      public:
         virtual void print(std::ostream& out) const = 0;
      ...
   };
   ```

   and implement the function in the derived clases.

   ```
   class Circle : public Shape {
      public:
         virtual void print(std::ostream& out) const
         {
            out << "Got a Circle.\n";
         }

      ....
   };
   ```
2. If you cannot solve your problem using a `virtual` member function, you'll need to resort to `dynamic_cast`.

   ```
   Shape* shapePtr = <some pointer>;
   Circle* circlePtr = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(shapePtr);
   if ( circlePtr ) {
      // Access Circle functionality.
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm at solution 2 right now. Can't do otherwise. I'm doing really hard to understand pointers. Bleh. What do I give into <some pointer>? Taken from my example that I have created 2 shape pointers?? objects?? like Shape* newRectangle= new Rectangle(4, 8); and Shape* newCircle= new Circle(10);

Comment: I tried http://hastebin.com/dalanasudu.xml or I misunderstood something. But it tells me "cannot use 'dynamic_cast' to convert from 'Shape &' to 'Circle *'"

Comment: @NoCanDo You should write `Circle* circlePtr = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(&object);` in your hastebin example to convert a reference to a pointer.