# Change base object in derived object

Tags: c++, inheritance

In one of my classes `GUI` I have a private variable for the class `User u`. In this `GUI` class I have a function for the user to login in then check if their account is admin or a normal user and then from that create either a `User` or `Admin` object. Admin is derived from user with a few more privileges. How do I set the private variable `User u` to be either an `Admin` object or `User` object after they login.

Comment: Read about polymorphism in your favourite C++ book.

Answer (score -2):

If the `Admin` class is extending the `User` class then you can use `User u` to represent both of them.

When you need only Admin and you don't know if `u` is an `Admin` or `User` object you can check it like this at runtime:

```
if(Admin * v = dynamic_cast<Admin*>(u)) {
   // u was safely casted to Admin
   v->doSomething();
}
```

---

**N.B.**
`dynamic_cast` is an operation with big cost you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500495/4532326) some workarounds.

Comment: I didn't vote, but the proposed solution won't lead to code with good / clean architecture. Sure, an admin "is a" user, but it's probably better to give different users different "roles".

Comment: @DanielJour I'm not judging the architecture.. I'm answering to the request of the question. In the question is written *Admin is derived from user*